# SimpleWebRTC with switchable Audio and Video call

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia, simplewebrtc, mediastream

I am using [SimpleWebRTC](https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC) for Audio Video calls. 
I am able to make Video call or Audio call individually as below.

For Audio:

```
var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
    url : myURL,
    localVideoEl : 'localAudio',
    autoRequestMedia : true,
    remoteVideosEl : '',
    debug : false,
    detectSpeakingEvents : true,
    autoAdjustMic : false,
    media : {
        video : false,
        audio : true
    },
    receiveMedia : {
        offerToReceiveAudio : 1,
        offerToReceiveVideo : 0
    }
});
```

For Video

```
webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
    url : result,   
    localVideoEl : 'localVideo',
    remoteVideosEl : '',
    autoRequestMedia : true,
    debug : false,
    detectSpeakingEvents : true,
    autoAdjustMic : false
});
```

My Video element:

```
<video id="localVideo" style="height: 200px;" oncontextmenu="return false;"></video>
```

With events:

```
webrtc.on('videoAdded', function (video, peer) {
            console.log('video is added', peer);
});
```

How can I switch video stream to audio one? Or vice versa? How can I effectively convert active video call to audio one, or and Audio call to video one without making a new SimpleWebRTC object?
I am okay with workarounds, if any.

I have tried is make a video call, and make use `webrtc.pauseVideo();` which still transmits the stream and uses my camera and bandwidth. I certainly don't want that.